# Enable debug print statements if compiled with debug flag

Tags: c++, debugging

Let's say I have a project with many functions. For debugging purpopses, I want each one of them print out a diagnostic message (or a few) when called:

```
int f(int arg) {
    cerr << "f() called with argument" << arg << endl;
    int ret = 42;
    cerr << "f() returned " << ret << endl;
    return ret;
}
```

and so on. In one function, there may be as many as five to six messages printed out on cerr. I want to be able to disable them unless a debug flag (like `NDEBUG`) is set. One thing I could do is wrap each cerr statement with an if-statement.

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
  const bool DEBUG_ON = true;
#else
  const bool DEBUG_ON = false;
#endif

int f(int arg) {
      if (DEBUG_ON) {
          cerr << "f() called with argument" << arg << endl;
      }
      int ret = 42;
      if (DEBUG_ON) {
          cerr << "f() returned " << ret << endl;
      }
      return ret;
}
```

But it can get really tedious and, in the end, virtually unreadable with a couple dozens of such statements. My idea was to replace `cerr` with a custom object with an overloaded `<<` operator which would send any arguments passed to it "into the void" like this:

```
class NullOutStream {
public:
    NullOutStream operator<<(...) {
        return *this;
    }
};

NullOutStream debug_out;

#ifdef NDEBUG
  #define debug_out cerr
#else
  #define debug_out debug_out
#endif
```

Although it works perfectly, it doesn't seem very elegant. Is there a standard/nicer way to accomplish this?

Comment: Normally (see <cassert>), `NDEBUG` means you're *not* in debug mode. I wouldn't reuse the same name for the object and the macro.

Comment: @aschepler Yeah, you're right, I was typing too quickly. My question still stands though.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "standard" way to do this. There are many logging/assertion libraries that deal with similar issues, and there are different approaches to solve this. A few things to keep in mind:

- It may or may not be desirable to keep the side effects of your log statement (as yours does). For example, if you did something like this:

  `debug_out << ++i;`

  This would increment `i` no matter whether you are in debug mode or not. This is probably desirable in this case. Conversely, if you do this:

  `debug_out << some_object.expensive_to_string_operation();`

  This would call `expensive_to_string_operation()` even when you are not in debug mode. This is probably not desirable in this case.

  This would not happen if you used `printf`-style debug macro, e.g. something like this:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
  #define logf(...)
#else
  #define logf(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)
#endif
```

The reason being that when in non-debug mode, the arguments would be removed by the preprocessor.

- You may want to do other things before or after each log statement, e.g. record a time stamp, flush a log file etc. It is possible to do this with streams by using destructor tricks, but it is more complicated to implement. It is much easier to do this using a function call, e.g. something like this:

  `#define log(msg) printf("%s: %s\n", timestamp(), msg)`
- You may want to record file name / line number with your logs. Again, this is easier to do with a function call than with a stream.
- Streams may be better if you want custom formatting by object type - the printf interface doesn't lend itself to that very well.

I would recommend to have a look at some existing logging libraries to get an idea of different approaches. I suggest looking at Google's glog library because it has an interesting combination of using streams while retaining the ability to do 'per call' things (e.g. record time stamps, line numbers etc).